# Returning element that is true in an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking for a simple way to return a node in my array that has its value of isStart == true. The method I have already created seems to only work on a singular array.

```js
this.nodes = [];

for (let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
  this.nodes[r] = [];
  for (let c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
    if (r == 12 && c == 6) {
      var isStart = true;
    } else {
      var isStart = false;
    }
    if (r == 12 && c == 44) {
      var isFinish = true;
    } else {
      var isFinish = false;
    }
    let node = new Node(r, c, isStart, isFinish, false);
    this.nodes[r].push(node);
  }
}
```

```js
getStartNode() {
  return board.nodes.findIndex(node => node.isStart == true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the array a parameter, so you can call it on any array.

```js
getStartNode(nodes) {
  return nodes.findIndex(node => node.isStart == true)
}
```

Then you can call `getStartNode(this.nodes[i])`

Comment: So would you just then put a loop in getStartNode calling getStartNode(this.nodes[i])

Comment: If you want to get the start node for every array of nodes, sure. If you just need it for the current array, you don't need a loop.